# intersection form

Tags: algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I have problem understanding the proof of this theorem on page 23 of Kirby's Topology of 4-manifolds:

Two closed oriented 4-manifolds are homotopy equivalent iff they have isomorphic intersection forms.

They consider a map $S^3\to S^2$v...v$S^2$ and the inverse image of $p_i$ (a point in $i$-th $S^2$) which are knots in $S^3$ and claim  this map is determined up to homotopy by the linking matrix of these knots in $S^3$. But I cannot figure out why such map is determined by this linking matrix up to homotopy. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of Pontrjagin-Thom construction: homotopy classes of such maps are in one-to-one correspondence with framed bordism classes of framed links in $S^3$. Moreover, the linking matrix is an invariant of a framed bordism class.

This is explained, among other places, in Scorpan's "The wild world of 4-manifolds", pages 143. and 230.